# Big Query Count Distinct multiple columns

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am new at Big Query and have recently connected GA4. Now I'm trying to use BQ as a source for reports.

I've got the following query

```
SELECT event_name, 
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "page_location") page_location,
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "click_type") click_type,
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "link_url") link_url, 
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "click_element") click_element
FROM `bq-ga4.events_20230917` AS result
WHERE event_name LIKE '%_links'
```

Which results in the following table
[image]

As you can see, row 1 and 3 in this result are exactly the same. What I want to achieve is this same table, but with a count distinct on the rows. In this example this would result in a table with 4 rows, row 1 having a count of 2 and the other rows a count of 1

How do I achieve this?  I've tried the following query

```
SELECT event_name, 
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "page_location") page_location,
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "click_type") click_type,
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "link_url") link_url, 
       (SELECT value.string_value
        FROM UNNEST(event_params)
        WHERE key = "click_element") click_element,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(page_location,click_type,link_url,click_element))) clicks
FROM `bq-ga4.events_20230917` AS result
WHERE event_name LIKE '%_links'
```

But this results just in an error: *Unrecognized name: page_location at*

Any pointers how to achieve this?